# RandomizedSearchCV OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into aan index-sized integer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, grid-search

I am trying to run a RandomizedSearchCV on a neural network to identify the optimal parameters. I have created the model function and the parameters distribution but i keep getting an Overflow error. How can I correct the error?

I have relooked the code and i am not sure where the error is; i think possibly on how i have defined the randomizedsearch?

```
# Model Definition

K.clear_session()

input_depth = features.shape[1]
output_depth = target.shape[1]

#np.random.seed(32)

def grid_search_model(layer_units_1, act_fn_1, layer_initialise_1, L1_ker_1, L2_ker_1, L1_act_1, bias_init_1, kernel_const_1, drop_1,
                      layer_units_2, act_fn_2, layer_initialise_2, L1_ker_2, L2_ker_2, L1_act_2, bias_init_2, kernel_const_2, drop_2,
                      layer_units_hidden, act_fn_hidden, layer_initialise_hidden, L1_ker_hidden, L2_ker_hidden, L1_act_hidden, bias_init_hidden, kernel_const_hidden, drop_hidden,
                      layer_initialise_output, L1_ker_output, L2_ker_output, L1_act_output, bias_init_output, kernel_const_output):
    model = Sequential()
    metric = Metrics()

    model.add(Dense(units = layer_units_1,
                    activation = act_fn_1,
                    kernel_initializer = layer_initialise_1,
                    kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = L1_ker_1, l2 = L2_ker_1),
                    activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(L1_act_1),
                    bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value = bias_init_1),
                    kernel_constraint = kernel_const_1,
                    input_shape=(input_depth,),
                    name='hidden_layer1'))

    model.add(Dropout(drop_1))

    model.add(Dense(units = layer_units_2,
                    activation = act_fn_2,
                    kernel_initializer = layer_initialise_2,
                    kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = L1_ker_2, l2 = L2_ker_2),
                    activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(L1_act_2),
                    bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value = bias_init_2),
                    kernel_constraint = kernel_const_2,
                    name='hidden_layer2'))

    model.add(Dropout(drop_2))

    for i in range(hidden_layer_no):
        model.add(Dense(units = hidden_layer_depth_hidden,
                        activation = act_fn_hidden,
                        kernel_initializer = layer_initialise_hidden,
                        kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = L1_ker_hidden, l2 = L2_ker_hidden),
                        activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(L1_act_hidden),
                        bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value = bias_init_hidden),
                        kernel_constraint = kernel_const_hidden))
        model.add(Dropout(drop_hidden))

    model.add(Dense(units = output_depth,
                    activation = 'softmax',
                    kernel_initializer = layer_initialise_output,
                    kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = L1_ker_output, l2 = L2_ker_output),
                    activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(L1_act_output),
                    bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value = bias_init_output),
                    kernel_constraint = kernel_const_output,
                    name='output_layer'))

  adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0, amsgrad=True, clipvalue=0.5, clipnorm=1) #0.0001 ln rate is the same #0.2 decay #learning rate 0.001 decay=0, lr rate = 0.001

  model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])#'categorical_accuracy'])

  return model

# Parameter definition

a = input_depth - (round((input_depth-output_depth)/3))

hyperparameters = {'layer_units_1' : [input_depth, a, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000],
                       'act_fn_1' : ['relu','sigmoid'],
                       'layer_initializer_1' : [None,
                                              keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=input_depth**(-0.5), seed=1),
                                              keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1),
                                              keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=1)],
                       'L1_ker_1' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L2_ker_1' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L1_act_1' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'bias_init_1' : [0,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0],
                       'kernel_const_1' : [None,
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=-1.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0),
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)],
                       'drop_1' : [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8],
                       'layer_units_2' : [input_depth, a, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000],
                       'act_fn_2' : ['relu','sigmoid'],
                       'layer_initializer_2' : [None,
                                              keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=input_depth**(-0.5), seed=1),
                                              keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1),
                                              keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=1)],
                       'L1_ker_2' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L2_ker_2' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L1_act_2' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'bias_init_2' : [0,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0],
                       'kernel_const_2' : [None,
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=-1.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0),
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)],
                       'drop_2' : [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8],
                       'layer_units_hidden' : [input_depth, a, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000],
                       'act_fn_hidden' : ['relu','sigmoid'],
                       'layer_initializer_hidden' : [None,
                                                   keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=input_depth**(-0.5), seed=1),
                                                   keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1),
                                                   keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=1)],
                       'L1_ker_hidden' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L2_ker_hidden' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L1_act_hidden' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'bias_init_hidden' : [0,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0],
                       'kernel_const_hidden' : [None,
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=-1.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0),
                                         keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)],
                       'drop_hidden' : [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8],
                       'layer_units_hidden' : [input_depth, a, 10, 50, 100, 200, 1000],
                       'layer_initializer_output' : [None,
                                                   keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=input_depth**(-0.5), seed=1),
                                                   keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1),
                                                   keras.initializers.he_uniform(seed=1)],
                       'L1_ker_output' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L2_ker_output' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'L1_act_output' : [None,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1],
                       'bias_init_output' : [0,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0],
                       'kernel_const_output' : [None,
                                              keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=-1.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0),
                                              keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0)]
                      }

# RandomizedSearchCV
metric = Metrics()
class_neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=grid_search_model, epochs=200)
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=class_neural_network, param_grid=hyperparameters, n_jobs = -1, pre_dispatch = 5, random_state = 42, return_train_score = True, verbose=10)
time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
grid = grid.fit(X_train_rus, y_train_rus_1, callbacks=[metric])
```

I expect the search to run, with no issues. I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-a4148e6688c1> in <module>()
      4 grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=class_neural_network, param_distributions=hyperparameters, n_jobs = -1, pre_dispatch = 5, random_state = 42, return_train_score = True, verbose=10)
      5 time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
----> 6 grid = grid.fit(X_train_rus, y_train_rus_1, callbacks=[metric])

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    720                 return results_container[0]
    721 
--> 722             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    723 
    724         results = results_container[0]

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1513         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1514             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
-> 1515             random_state=self.random_state))

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    694 
    695             def evaluate_candidates(candidate_params):
--> 696                 candidate_params = list(candidate_params)
    697                 n_candidates = len(candidate_params)
    698 

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in __iter__(self)
    261             # look up sampled parameter settings in parameter grid
    262             param_grid = ParameterGrid(self.param_distributions)
--> 263             grid_size = len(param_grid)
    264             n_iter = self.n_iter
    265 

OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your parameters `dict` is composed only of lists, e.g. you're specifying `'bias_init_1' : [0,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0]`.
This means that effectively you have specified a **discrete grid** of parameters.
It seems like the `sklearn` code is trying to calculate the size of your discrete parameter grid and since this is a cartesian product of all your parameter lists, you get a very large size, too large for an integer.
From what I gather, you get this error because when specifying parameters as a grid, `sklearn` will try to access them by index, so the total size of the grid should fit in an integer.

When doing cross-validation with a randomized search, it's better to specify a **distriubtion** for your parameters, like so:

```py
import scipy.stats.distributions as dists

param_grid = dict(
    param1=dists.uniform(0, 1),        # continuous distribution
    param2=dists.randint(16, 512 + 1), # discrete distribution
    param3=['foo', 'bar'],             # specifying possible values directly
)
```

When specifying the parameters grid this way `sklearn` won't try to calculate the size of your parmater grid (since it's technically infinite) and therefore this should prevent the error you got.

Using continuous distributions for continuous variables will also improve your effective coverage of the search space, so it's a better CV approach in general.
Notice also in the above example that you can combine discrete parameters (e.g. `param3`) with continuous ones.